# Select values where tow different conditions

Tags: sql, select, criteria-api

I have a Questions group table like follows:

`ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, VERSION_ID`

Versions table columns are:

`ID, NUMBER, VERSION_STATE`

`VERSION_STATE` is an enumerated that can be 0, 1 or 2.

I need to select all questions group that its version has thev`VERSION_STATE` 0 or 1, but if there is a questions group with a `VERSION_STATE = 0` I don't have to return the questions group with the `VERSION_STATE = 1`.

The simplest approach is:

```
SELECT distinct QG.id FROM healthsafety.hs_questions_group QG
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM healthsafety.hs_version) VERSION
ON QG.VERSION_ID = VERSION.ID
WHERE 
VERSION.VERSION_STATE=0
OR VERSION.VERSION_STATE=1
```

The problem is that this query returns all questions group with the `VERSION_STATE` 0 or 1. If I remove the or clause, and there are not questions groups with `VERSION_STATE = 0`, I need to return the questions groups with `VERSION_STATE = 1`.

I think that I need an if else or case statement but I am stucked. Any Idea?

Note that I have to implement this using criteria, so I need to use the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (

SELECT OG.ID,OG.NAME,OG.DESCRIPTION,VERSION.ID,VERSION.NUMBER,VERSION.VERSION_STATE,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY OG.ID ORDER BY VERSION.VERSION_STATE ASC) as INDICATOR
FROM healthsafety.hs_questions_group QG
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM healthsafety.hs_version) VERSION
ON QG.VERSION_ID = VERSION.ID
WHERE 
VERSION.VERSION_STATE=0
OR VERSION.VERSION_STATE=1
) AS ABC

WHERE (ABC.VERSION_STATE = 0 and ABC.INDICATOR = 1) 
OR (ABC.VERSION_STATE = 1 and ABC.INDICATOR = 1)
```

Comment: This query returns the same results than mine. Maybe I did not express myself well. I need to return all questions groups with `VERSION_STATE = 0` and only if there are no results, return questions groups with  `VERSION_STATE = 1`

Comment: @VíctorGómez I forgot to put `()` for those two conditions in `where` clause, check again

Comment: I made a query based on yours (I order by `VERSION_STATE` another column in over function and I changed the where conditions) and now I get the correct results

Answer (score 0):

Using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and a `union all` where the second query uses `not exists()` to only return rows where `version_state=1` when rows with `version_state=0` do not exist.

```
;with cte as (
  select qg.id, v.version_state
  from healthsafety.hs_questions_group qg
    inner join healthsafety.hs_version version v
      on qg.version_id = v.id
  where v.version_state in (0,1)
)
select id
from cte
where version_state = 0

union all

select qg.id
from cte
where version_state = 1
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from cte
    where version_state = 0
)
```

Comment: This query returns the same results than mine. Maybe I did not express myself well. I need to return all questions groups with `VERSION_STATE = 0` and only if there are no results, return questions groups with  `VERSION_STATE = 1`

Comment: @VíctorGómez Updated based on your clarification.